# Laravel 5 get JSON Response

Tags: jquery, laravel

I try to recieve an error message, but i dont get my actual text.

This is my JS.

```
$('form input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = jQuery(this).parents("form:first");
        var dataString = form.serialize();
        var formAction = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : formAction,
            data : dataString,
            success : function(data){
                if (data.redirect) {
                    // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                    window.location.href = data.redirect;
                }
            },
            error : function(data){
                $('input[name="email"]').val('');
                $('input[name="password"]').val('');
                $('.alert-danger').show();
                $('#message').text(data.responseText);
            }

        },"json");
    });
```

As a result i get only

```
 {"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}
```

**But of course i want to fetch only the text.**
e.g "The email field is required."

In my Controller i just have a json response

```
return response()->json([
            'data' => $errors,
        ]);
```

And here is my Console:

[image]

And if i try to get the message with `$('#message').text(data.responseText.email);` 
i get nothing back.

Comment: I tried it with `data.email[0]` and with `data.responseText.email[0]` still no result.

Comment: `JSON.parse(data.responseText).email`

Answer (score 1):

Okay i finally found the solution.
I needed to add the pareseJSON 
`var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);`

After this i can fetch the value with `errors.email[0]`

So the error function looks like this:

```
error : function(data){
                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

                $('input[name="email"]').val('');
                $('input[name="password"]').val('');
                $('.alert-danger').show();
                $('#message').text(errors.email[0]);
            }
```